# Attaching value to array isn't impossible, how to add a value to a button/array/image?

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

I just started coding, so I just simply don't know the most things. I want to make a simple game. I will explain shortly: When the user pressed the "Click to start" game button, 7 out of the 52 cards in a card deck will be revealed. I did this by creating several buttons that hold an image of a back of a card. So when the user clicks the button, 7 cards will be opened with a random card.

First off, I created an array to add all my photo names to the view controller, like this:

```
var MasterAllCards = ["2_of_clubs", "2_of_spades", "2_of_diamonds", "2_of_hearts", "3_of_clubs", "3_of_spades", "3_of_diamonds", "3_of_hearts", "4_of_clubs", "4_of_spades", "4_of_diamonds", "4_of_hearts", "5_of_clubs", "5_of_spades", "5_of_diamonds", "5_of_hearts", "6_of_clubs", "6_of_spades", "6_of_diamonds", "6_of_hearts", "7_of_clubs", "7_of_spades","7_of_diamonds","7_of_hearts", "8_of_clubs", "8_of_spades", "8_of_diamonds", "8_of_hearts", "9_of_clubs", "9_of_spades", "9_of_diamonds", "9_of_hearts", "10_of_clubs", "10_of_spades", "10_of_diamonds", "10_of_hearts", "jack_of_clubs", "jack_of_spades", "jack_of_diamonds", "jack_of_hearts", "queen_of_clubs", "queen_of_spades", "queen_of_diamonds", "queen_of_hearts", "king_of_clubs", "king_of_spades", "king_of_diamonds", "king_of_hearts", "ace_of_clubs", "ace_of_spades", "ace_of_diamonds", "ace_of_hearts"]
```

Than I created an IBAction outlet to my view controller, from my click to start button as followed:

```
@IBAction func testt(sender: UIButton) {
    TheGoButton.enabled = false
    TheGoButton.hidden = true
    SlotCard1.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Cardslot1")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard1.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard1")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard2.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard2")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard3.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard3")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard4.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard4")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard5.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard5")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard6.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard6")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    Playablecard7.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Playablecard7")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    //sender.setImage(UIImage(named: randomcardpicker("Cardslot1")), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
}
```

My function "randomcardpicker" is as followed:

```
func randomcardpicker (WhatCarduPlay: String) -> String {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(MasterAllCards.count)))
    let RandomCard = AllCards[randomIndex]
    let RandomValueOfTheCard = AllValues[randomIndex]
    MasterAllCards.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
    AllValues.removeAtIndex(randomIndex)
    StoreHereAllValues.append(RandomValueOfTheCard)
    StoreHereAllCards.append(RandomCard)

    return RandomCard
}
```

As you can see I added a lot of random things, because I can not figure out how to put an addition value to an array, like an Int. Now the button will change to the image correctly, but this button/image needs to hold a value that I can use later to compare 2 values. I read something about Enums, but I could not figure out if this will work at my code.

So my question: How to add a value to this button, so I can use this to compare it to other buttons in the future?

As I am writing this, I was wondering to let the value of the image, be the title of this button, so I can read the value out easy. Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: Whoops, I now see that I did not explained the game at all... The game I want to re-create is Magic Towers. Just for fun :)

Comment: There's a lot of ways you could do this.  The simplest might be to set the `tag` property of each of the buttons.  You could also store references to the buttons in an array in a known order.  You could subclass UIButton to keep some additional state.

Comment: Cool buddy, did not know about the tags. Now my problem is solved :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach might be to set the `tag` property on each `UIButton` to determine which one you're dealing with.